# USB stick after incomplete run of dd

Tags: usb, uefi, dd, parted, cloning

I have a hard drive with 2 equally sized partitions and a USB stick with 70% of capacity of the hard drive.

Now I use `dd if=/dev/harddrive of=/dev/usbdrive bs=1M` to "clone" my hard
drive.

I would expect `fdisk -l` to show me either one partition on the usb drive or both even though the second is corrupted of course. Turns out `fdisk -l` only shows me the partition that has been completely copied.

So far so good. I expect `parted` to see the same state as `fdisk` and allow me to delete the corrupted partition. But `parted` sees nothing and I cannot mount the intact partition.

In other words, I have a completely intact partition (I am not interested in the data in the corrupted partition anyhow) and I believe I have the correct meta information about that partition in the first bytes of my USB stick. but I do not know how to easily access that partition.

Also I would like to know if all the meta information about the partitions is at the start of the USB stick. The fact that `parted` fails at this job suggest it is not, but I find that hard to believe.

In case it matters, the original hard drive is UEFI booted.

Answer (score 1):

with *gdisk* I could remove the corrupted partition and repair the USB stick.

after executing `gdisk /dev/sda` on the command line, *gdisk* offered to fix partition information. No need to know any command, I just had to accept.

After that I queried *gdisk* about each partition with the `i` command. That revealed the same info as on the original hard disk. The second partition was shown with the original size even though that would not fit on the USB drive. From this I conclude, that all the meta information regarding the partitions is indeed at the start of the drive.

I then used the `d` command of *gdisk* to remove the corrupt partition. All seems good so far.

I need to add here that my original disk was *GPT*. If it were *MBR*, then you would have had to use *fdisk* instead of *gdisk*.

Comment: Glad to hear you found something that worked. Could you explain a little bit about the steps you took with gdisk to solve your problem? Part of your initial question also says "I would like to know if all the meta information about the partitions is at the start of the USB stick" -- do you have an answer for that, or should it be removed from your question? Thanks!